# Notice: Undefined variable: thumbnail

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

I have a grid setup on my portfolio page and for whatever reason I keep getting these two errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: thumbnail in
>   /home/hometo10/public_html/wp-content/themes/swank/archive-portfolio.php
>   on line 22
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /home/hometo10/public_html/wp-content/themes/swank/archive-portfolio.php
>   on line 22

Here is my archive-portfolio.php code

```
<?php
//* The custom portfolio post type archive template


//* Add the portfolio blurb section
add_action( 'genesis_before_content', 'swank_portfolioblurb_before_content' );
function swank_portfolioblurb_before_content() {

    genesis_widget_area( 'portfolioblurb', array(
    'before' => '<div class="portfolioblurb">',
    ) );

}

//* Add the featured image after post title
add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'swank_portfolio_grid' );
function swank_portfolio_grid() {

    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ){
        echo '<div class="portfolio-featured-image">';
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() .'" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID, 'portfolio-featured');
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

}

//* Remove the ad widget
remove_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'adspace_before_loop' );

//* Remove author box
remove_action( 'genesis_after_entry', 'genesis_do_author_box_single', 8 );

//* Remove the post meta function
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_post_meta' );

//* Remove the post info function
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_post_info', 12 );

//* Force full width content layout
add_filter( 'genesis_pre_get_option_site_layout', '__genesis_return_full_width_content' );

//* Remove the post content
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_content' );

//* Remove the footer widgets
remove_action( 'genesis_before_footer', 'genesis_footer_widget_areas' );

genesis();
```

Comment: Sorry forgot website link: http://www.hometowndesignco.com/portfolio/

Comment: In `swank_portfolio_grid()` replace `echo get_the_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID, 'portfolio-featured');` with  `echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'portfolio-featured');`

Answer (score 1):

It is complaining that `$thumbnail` is undefined because it's undefined, unknown, it's been pulled out of thin air.

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID, 'portfolio-featured');
```

This, is the very first time `$thumbnail` is mentioned, where did it come from?  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I have no idea and neither does PHP, hence the warning. You could change it to `$thai_chicken_curry->ID` and it would behave the same way, and generate the same warning.

> You can easily fix this by *comungulatorianing* the code

Notice that the word comungulatorianing doesn't exist, so you might have wondered what I was referring to. PHP did the same when it saw the undefined variable.

When PHP encounters these kinds of issues, it substitutes a `null`-ish/falsey value, so that function will likely be retrieving the ID of the current post instead ( as defined in the WP docs )

**So how do you fix it?** You have several options:

- figure out where to get the thumbnail from somehow and assign that attachment post to a variable  called `$thumbnail` so it's now defined/known
- replace that line with something that does what you want, aka display the thumbnail with the size `portfolio-featured`, which you can probably do via `the_post_thumbnail( 'postfolio-featured')` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/
- Go to where you got the code for that function from ( original theme author? ), and raise a support ticket for this bug

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't read [Tom's answer to your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/354642/38603), read that first. He gives a good explanation (as always!) of *why* you are getting an error. This is important information to understand when doing WP development, and he explains it well, so I won't repeat that here.

I do have a suggestion that may fix your issue, which is the undefined `$thumbnail` value.

In context of how it is used, it appears the original author (I assumed you got this from somewhere other than yourself) expects this to be an object (hence the `->`).  I tried to find where you got it from, since there are a lot of "re-used" and "re-hashed" code snippets out there for just about everything WP related - some good, some bad.

It appears to come [from here](https://gist.github.com/joshrogersdesign/08a1c2ee4bcbdb82e52a). Unfortunately, that doesn't provide a solution. If he's the original author, the error originates there, and there's not enough context to determine where he intended `$thumbnail` to come from.

So looking strictly at the WP functions involved, we can probably make a "best guess" that the author intended this to be the current `$post` object. (That's *my* guess anyway).

The WP function `get_the_post_thumbnail()` expects the first parameter to be the **post ID** ([see documentation here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/)). The ID is contained within the object (`$post->ID`).

In this case, the original snippet author represented `$post->ID` with `$thumbnail->ID` which would be fine if `$thumbnail` was previously defined as the `$post` object, but it's not.

So to fix this - or at least to attempt to fix it - we need to define the object being passed. We'll assume the current `$post` is the necessary object, and that it's available as a global.  Here's the change you to that section you can try:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ){

    global $post;

    echo '<div class="portfolio-featured-image">';
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() .'" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '">';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'portfolio-featured');
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

This answer took longer to write than looking these things up on the web (a total of about 2 minutes). So my suggestion is to learn some of these things, how they fit together, and how they are used. Knowing what Tom explained and what I explained, you'd be able to figure this out on your own relatively quickly. The most important part would be to learn how to use WP's documentation for its functions (note where I referenced the docs above). You can use that to figure out what the function is expecting and work backwards from there.

**Update**

Another possible approach would be to use WP's `get_the_ID()` function to get the post ID ([see docs here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/)).  So instead of using the `global $post`, you would use `get_the_ID()` to get the ID of the current post so you could pass that in `get_the_post_thumbnail()`.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ){

    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    echo '<div class="portfolio-featured-image">';
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() .'" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '">';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'portfolio-featured');
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ALL very helpful and useful information. I learned so much about the Wordpress functionality from troubleshooting this myself but you two both put "human" understanding into it and FIXED my problem. Thank you to you both, saved my website and sanity!